# Detect when link is clicked WebView (Mac)

Tags: macos, webview, delegates

I'm trying to detect when I click a link in a WebView.
I set the delegate with

```
[_WebCont delete:self];
_WebCont.policyDelegate = self;
```

and

```
WebPolicyDecisionListener
```

I'm using this as my listener:

```
- (void)_WebCont:(WebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation request:(NSURLRequest *)request frame:(WebFrame *)frame decisionListener:(id<WebPolicyDecisionListener>)listener {
    NSString *url = request.URL.absoluteString;
    url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"*load %@",url];
    [self sendMessage:url];
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Click: %@",url]);

}
```

But when ever I click a link in the view it never logs anything.
Any help on fixing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To implement a policy listener you need do this:

WebPolicyDecisionListener.h:

```
// ...
@interface WebPolicyDecisionListener: NSObject {
// ...
}


// Implement PolicyDelegate
-(void)webView:(WebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation
                                                          request:(NSURLRequest *)request
                                                            frame:(WebFrame *)frame
                                                 decisionListener:(id<WebPolicyDecisionListener>)listener;

-(void)webView:(WebView *)webView decidePolicyForNewWindowAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation
                                                         request:(NSURLRequest *)request
                                                    newFrameName:(NSString *)frameName
                                                decisionListener:(id <WebPolicyDecisionListener>)listener;
// ...
@end
```

WebPolicyDecisionListener.m

```
@implementation WebPolicyDecisionListener
// ...
- (void)webView:(WebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation
                                                           request:(NSURLRequest *)request
                                                             frame:(WebFrame *)frame
                                                  decisionListener:(id<WebPolicyDecisionListener>)listener
{
  if (WebNavigationTypeLinkClicked == [[actionInformation objectForKey:WebActionNavigationTypeKey] intValue])
  {
    // link was clicked do something with it...
  }
  [listener use]; // Say for webview to do it work...
}


-(void)webView:(WebView *)webView decidePolicyForNewWindowAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation
                                                         request:(NSURLRequest *)request
                                                    newFrameName:(NSString *)frameName
                                                decisionListener:(id <WebPolicyDecisionListener>)listener
{
  if (WebNavigationTypeLinkClicked == [[actionInformation objectForKey:WebActionNavigationTypeKey] intValue])
  {
    // link was clicked and webview want to open it in new window do something with it...
  }
  [listener ignore]; // ignore webview default implementation...
}
// ...
@end
```

and somewhere in your code something like this:

```
WebPolicyDecisionListener* listener = [[WebPolicyDecisionListener alloc] init];
// ...
[_WebCont setPolicyDelegate:listener];
```

Comment: So I should add thr method?

Comment: Thanks. In my case I'm detecting downloadable `Blob` HTML5 object links (i.e. something like `blob:https://mydomain/BLOB_ID`), and I can do that, but I don't figure out how to let this file to be downloaded rather than visualized (that is what happens right now)...